# Como pegar o valor de TextBox criadas dinamicamente?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, textbox

Tenho um formulario que recebe uma quantidade de TextBox que devem ser instanciados, a pagina então gera os textboxes, porém não sei como poderei pegar os valores.

```
hd = Request.QueryString["qtHD"];
mem = Request.QueryString["qtMem"];
hdnum = Convert.ToInt16(hd);

while (hdnum >= 1)
{
    text1 = new TextBox();
    String txtBox = "txtTamHD" + hdnum.ToString();
    text1.ID = txtBox;
    form1.Controls.Add(text1);
    hdnum--;
}
```

Comment: Pode por favor colocar um exemplo de código?

Comment: Não sabe como pegar quais valores?

Comment: To usando esse trecho de código pra criar os TextBox, eu queria pegar os valores que o usuario digitou neles.

`hd = Request.QueryString["qtHD"];  
mem = Request.QueryString["qtMem"];
hdnum = Convert.ToInt16(hd);  
            while (hdnum >= 1)
            {
                text1 = new TextBox();
                String txtBox = "txtTamHD" + hdnum.ToString();
                text1.ID = txtBox;
                form1.Controls.Add(text1);
                hdnum--;
            }`

Comment: Provavelmente os dados submetidos pelos controles não estarão na forma de query-string. Tente usar Request.Params["qtHD"].

Comment: esse é o codigo é o que recebe o numero e instancia o textbox, estou pegando os parametros via GET e está funcionando normalmente com QueryString, meu problema é como pegar os dados dos controles que estou criando agora.

Comment: @rafaslide não esqueça de marcar como correta a resposta que mais te ajudou. Vc também pode adicionar uma resposta sua, caso nenhuma das outras tenha sido satisfatória.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No WebForms, para que os valores de controles criados dinamicamente sejam recuperados, você deve assegurar que todos os controles sejam criados e adicionados à hierarquia da página antes do evento ProcessPostData.

Depois desse evento no ciclo de vida da página, você não deve mais alterar a hierarquia de controles da página, pelo menos no que diz repeito a controles que postam dados.

No google imagens tem umas boas referências sobre o [ciclo de vida da página](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=pagelifecycle&espv=210&es_sm=122&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=L4kPU8SUOYS3kAebvIA4&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAw&biw=1366&bih=663)... na verdade, foi toda essa complexidade que me motivou a mudar para o ASP.NET MVC.

**EDIT 2** Imagem do ciclo de vida da página

[image: Ciclo de vida da página]
http://www.nullskull.com/articles/20051227.asp

**EDIT 3**

Para intercepatar o evento Init da página, vá no código da mesma e faça assim:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);

    // ... seu código de criação dos controles dinâmicos aqui
}
```

Comment: Eu sou novo nessa área, programo apenas há 6 meses, pra mim isso ai que voce disse é meio grego, como eu poderia adicionar o controle à hierarquia da página? Não sei como fazer algo antes do evento LoadPostData, ouvi muito bem do ASP.NET MVC. Estou procurando estudar aos poucos

Comment: Adicionar um controle à hierarquia da página significa adicionar o controle (no caso o TextBox) em qualquer lugar da página usando `Controls.Add`.

Comment: Me enganei, o nome do evento é ProcessPostData.

Comment: O que eu quero dizer com antes do ProcessPostData, é criar os controles TextBox dinâmicos em qualquer dos eventos da página que venham antes dele, por exemplo: OnInit, OnPreInit e outros... veja as figuras do google imagens de que falei, assim terá uma idéia da ordem dos eventos.

Comment: Revendo agora a imagem (editei a resposta e postei a imagem), você tem que criar os controles e adicionar na página ou dentro de qualquer outro controle até o evento `OnInitComplete`.

Answer (score 2):

Como o @MiguelAngelo comentou, a pegadinha está no **ciclo de vida da página**. Controles dinâmicos devem ser recriados na etapa de `Page_Init` para que existam *antes* do carregamento do `viewstate`. Isto significa que, *de alguma forma*, você deve salvar quantas caixas de texto você criou para recria-las novamente, **utilizando o mesmo ID**.

**Sugestão:**

1. Crie um atributo do tipo `List<TextBox>` (vamos chamar de `CamposDinamicos`)
2. Escreva um método que receba tudo que ele precisa para criar as caixas de texto. Ele não deve acessar nada fora dele, apenas receber seus argumentos e criar os `TextBoxes` no `CamposDinamicos`. O mínimo que ele deve receber é a quantidade de campos.
3. Chame esse método no `Page_Init`. Os argumentos para ele talvez devam ser recuperados da `Session`.
4. Quando precisar acessar o valor dos campos dinâmicos, procure por eles na lista `CamposDinamicos` e não em `FindControls()`

Esta é uma versão traduzida da resposta original que postei em https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11992311/get-text-from-dynamically-created-textbox-in-asp-net/11992384#11992384.

Comment: +1 ai pela explicação, e por mencionar o view-state... tinha até me esquecido dele, agora que uso MVC já faz tempo.

Answer (score 0):

Opa!

Então..

Você pode fazer um `foreach` de Controls.. Tipo esse: `foreach (Control controle in this.Controls) { }`
Aí você consegue varrer todos os controles do seu form.
Faz um `if (controle.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))` pra ver se é um TextBox e já era! ;)

Ajudou?